# Eloquent Where clause for nested jsonb. postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a column in my table as follows:

```
{
  1:{type: 0},
  2:{type: 1}...
}
```

i have tried using using `whereJsonContains('table.column->type', 0)` but it's not working,
`whereRaw("table->column @> '{\"type\": 0}'::jsonb");` is not working either, i guess because of the nested json structure. How can i make this work?

Comment: Did you simply try : `->whereJsonContains('your.column', ['type' => '0'])` ?

Comment: I did try that but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple suggestions i ended up using this code:

```
$model->whereRaw("(
                SELECT
                COUNT(elements.*) > 0
                FROM
                    jsonb_each(table.colum) elements
                WHERE
                elements.value->>'type' = ?
            )", [$validated_request['type']]);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

At root your JSON is not an array, but an object (notice the index which starts at 1 and brackets which enclose the data). You can't perform `whereJsonContains` on objects. You should either convert your JSON root to array, or do a comprehensive lookup:

### Case 1:

```
[
  {type: 0},
  {type: 1}...
]
```

I advise this code:

```
DB::table('table')->whereJsonContains('column->type', 0)->get();
```

### Case 2

```
DB::table('table')
    ->where('column->1->type', 0)
    ->orWhere('column->2->type', 1)
    ->get();
```

For further reference consult Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

I have data like `[{"value": "example.co"}]` or `[{"value": "example.co"}, {"value": "example.uk"}, {"value": "example.pk"}, ... ]` in table column `domains`  and above all mention method did not worked. I ended up using that code.

```
DB::table('table')->where("domains", '@>', '[{"value":"example.uk"}]')->get();
```

Or you can use that

```
$query = 'example.uk';
DB::table('table')->where("domains", '@>', '[' . json_encode(['value' => $query]) . ']')->get();
```